# put(field, value) method from SObject class throws System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Datetime

Tags: apex, json, datetime, deserialize

I have encountered the error *System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Datetime* and I can't find what is the reason for this error.

The context is as follows. I have a class with the `@RestResource` annotation and part of its logic is shown below:

I use the following code snippet to maintain a relationship between the fields sent in the JSON and the field it references in Salesforce.

```
private static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> notNullabelFields = new Map < String, Schema.SObjectField> {
    'origin' => Account.Origin__c,
    'webId' => Account.WebId__c,
    'documentId' => Account.DocumentId__c,
    'phone' => Account.Phone,
    'language' => Account.Language__c,
    'email' => Account.PersonEmail,
    'prefContactStart' => Account.PreferedContactStart__c,
};
```

I maintain a wrapper class where I deserialize the JSON request I receive.

```
 private class RequestData
 {
     public String origin {
         get;
         set {origin = value; setReceivedFields('origin');}}
     public String webId {
         get;
         set {webId = value; setReceivedFields('webId');}}
     public String documentID {
         get;
         set {documentId = value; setReceivedFields('documentID');}}
     public String phone {
         get;
         set {phone = value; setReceivedFields('phone');}}
     public String language {
         get;
         set {language = value; setReceivedFields('language');}}
     public String email {
         get;
         set {email = value; setReceivedFields('email');}}
     public Datetime prefContactStart {
         get;
         set {prefContactStart = value; setReceivedFields('prefContactStart');}}

     private Object get(String property)
        {
            String jsonFormatRequestDataInstance = Json.serialize(this);
            Map<String, Object> untypedRequestDataInstance = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonFormatRequestDataInstance);

            return untypedRequestDataInstance.get(property);
        }
}
```

*The `get` method of the wrapper class `RequestData` is used to dynamically obtain the value of the property.*

When the **WS** is called, the request is deserialized into an object of the wrapper class type.

```
RequestData reqData = (RequestData) JSON.deserializeStrict(request.requestBody.toString(), RequestData.class);
```

The problem is happening in the code snippet I attach below. What I am trying to do is to dynamically map the values received in the JSON into the appropriate fields in a Salesforce record, as long as these values are not **null**.

```
Account acc = new Account();

for (String field : notNullabelFields.keySet())
{
    if (reqData.get(field) != null)
    {
        acc.put(notNullabelFields.get(field), reqData.get(field));
    }
}
```

When I send the request from Postman the following error appears:

> System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Datetime

I don't understand the reason.

- Deserialization in the wrapper class is correctly performed (checked)
- The `get` method of the wrapper class `RequestData` returns a value of type `Object`.
- The second parameter expected by the `put` method of the `SObject` class is of type `Object`.

At what point is the conversion from `Object` to `String` done?

---

I have tested 'manually' mapping the value of the JSON field `prefContactStart` to the Salesforce field `Account.PreferredContactStart__c` and no exception is thrown. In fact, the field in Salesforce is updated correctly.

```
acc.PreferedContactStart__c = reqData.prefContactStart;
```

#### Edit:

Attached is an example of the JSON I receive;

```
{
  "origin":"origin example",
  "webId":"1234",
  "documentId": "1111111",
  "phone":"+34666666666",
  "language": "German",
  "email": "example@test.test",
  "prefContactStart": "2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Comment: What does your date/time value look like in the JSON? Is it an ISO string? You likely need to convert whatever you receive into an actual Datetime explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I receive an ISO string. For the field `prefContactStart` I receive something like that `2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z`. I will update my initial message to attach an example of the JSON I am receiving.

Answer (score 1):

JSON only has the following types: Map/Object, Array, String, Number, Boolean and null. it does not have a way to express date-time values, so by convention, we use ISO-8601. The round-trip between your wrapper and an untyped deserialization results in the date time becoming a string. You'd have to reparse the date time back into a `DateTime`. That's quite a bit of extra work to apparently save a few lines of code. Shorter isn't always better. Skip the unnecessarily expensive JSON serialization/deserialization and just write lines of code explicitly for the detection and assignment of the values.

Edit:

> If I deserialize into my wrapper class, why doesn't the direct `acc.PreferedContactStart__c = reqData.prefContactStart` assignment throw any error? Maybe you are suggesting that the problem is in the `get` method from my wrapper class where I serialize and deserialize?

The `acc.PreferedContactStart__c = reqData.prefContactStart` is assigning a `DateTime` to a `DateTime`. This is perfectly fine. The types are compatible (they are, after all, the same type), so the assignment is allowed.

The problem lies here:

```
String jsonFormatRequestDataInstance = Json.serialize(this);
Map<String, Object> untypedRequestDataInstance = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonFormatRequestDataInstance);
```

In the first line, you take your object and convert it to a JSON string. This is the JSON which you claimed you received, which matches what I'd expect:

```
{
  "origin":"origin example",
  "webId":"1234",
  "documentId": "1111111",
  "phone":"+34666666666",
  "language": "German",
  "email": "example@test.test",
  "prefContactStart": "2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Now, in the second line, you're using `JSON.deserializeUntyped`. JSON only has six types, as discussed in the first paragraph. That means that `JSON.deserializeUntyped` can only ever deserialize to one of those six types. This method doesn't detect, for example, if it's an ISO-8601-formatted string, and it doesn't know how to deserialize an object into a class like `RequestData`; anything that looks like an Object comes out as a Map.

As a more concrete example, consider:

```
Object value1 = JSON.deserialize('"2023-08-31T12:34:56.000Z"', DateTime.class);
Object value2 = JSON.deserializeUntyped('"2023-08-31T12:34:56.000Z"');
Assert.isTrue(value1 instanceOf DateTime);
Assert.isTrue(value2 instanceOf String);
```

As you can see, `JSON.deserialize` knows the type (we've provided it), and it returns a parsed `DateTime` object. However, `JSON.deserializeUntyped` doesn't know about the `DateTime` object, and so it returns the value as a `String`.

In other words, your JSON would be represented by the following Apex code:

```
Map<String, Object> results = new Map<String, Object> {
  'origin'=>'origin example',
  'webId'=>'1234',
  'documentId'=> '1111111',
  'phone'=>'+34666666666',
  'language'=> 'German',
  'email'=> 'example@test.test',
  'prefContactStart'=> '2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z'
};
```

Notice that `prefContactStart` is a `String`, not a `DateTime`. This is the source of the error. If we substitute the variable's values into the line where the exception is thrown, we get:

```
acc.put(Account.PreferedContactStart__c, '2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z');
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
acc.PreferedContactStart__c = '2023-06-26T11:00:00.000Z';
```

As you can see, that won't work. You first need to detect the field's type, then parse if appropriate.

As I said originally, sometimes more code is better. You have to create more work to properly deal with the data, instead of just using the wrapper data directly. To properly support this kind of design, you'd have to write something like my example [Xml2JSON](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/149650/2984) class. You'll see in that example that we use type sniffing with some regular expressions in an attempt to do the right thing. This is far more code than if you'd just use the wrapper data directly.

However, if you really wanted to make this work, you could use a backing variable for your wrapper. Here's how I'd probably do that:

```
class RequestData {
  Map<String, Object> values {
    get {
      if(values == null) {
        values = new Map<String, Object>();
      }
      return values;
    }
    set;
  }
  public String origin {
    get { return (String) values.get('origin'); }
    set { values.put('origin', value); }
  }
  public String webId {
    get { return (String) values.get('webId'); }
    set { values.put('webId', value); }
  }
  public String documentID {
    get { return (String) values.get('documentID'); }
    set { values.put('documentID', value); }
  }
  public String phone {
    get { return (String) values.get('phone'); }
    set { values.put('phone', value); }
  }
  public String language {
    get { return (String) values.get('language'); }
    set { values.put('language', value); }
  }
  public String email {
    get { return (String) values.get('email'); }
    set { values.put('email', value); }
  }
  public Datetime prefContactStart {
    get { return (Datetime) values.get('prefContactStart'); }
    set { values.put('prefContactStart', value); }
  }
  public Set<String> getReceivedFields() {
    return values.keySet().clone();
  }
  public Object getValue(String property) {
    return values.get(property);
  }
}
```

Now, all the values are preserved in a map cleverly called `values`, and each getter and setter reads to and writes from this map. Each field that is set will be in the keySet, which I demonstrate by way of `getReceivedFields`, and you can dynamically get any property with `getValue`.

If you don't ever intend to serialize to JSON and/or write to any of the fields, you can omit the getters, resulting in a clean:

```
class RequestData {
  Map<String, Object> values {
    get {
      if(values == null) {
        values = new Map<String, Object>();
      }
      return values;
    }
    set;
  }
  public String origin { set { values.put('origin', value); } }
  public String webId { set { values.put('webId', value); } }
  public String documentID { set { values.put('documentID', value); } }
  public String phone { set { values.put('phone', value); } }
  public String language { set { values.put('language', value); } }
  public String email { set { values.put('email', value); } }
  public Datetime prefContactStart { set { values.put('prefContactStart', value); } }
  public Set<String> getReceivedFields() {
    return values.keySet().clone();
  }
  public Object getValue(String property) {
    return values.get(property);
  }
}
```

This eliminates the ability to read the properties directly, but also cuts the code by nearly half.

Comment: If I deserialize into my wrapper class, why doesn't the direct `acc.PreferedContactStart__c = reqData.prefContactStart` assignment throw any error? 

Maybe you are suggesting that the problem is in the `get` method from my wrapper class where I serialize and deserialize?

Comment: @Tzinm I performed a massive edit that goes into far more detail about the problem and potential solutions. In short, yes, the problem is the roundtrip serialization/deserialization.